# In Gradle, how to perform processing after all subprojects' `build.gradle` files have been processed?

Tags: gradle

I would like to go through all the dependencies of all the configurations after all the subproject's (including those multiple levels down) have been processed so that:

```
rootProject.getConfigurations().each { configuration ->
    println "${configuration}: ${configuration.getAllDependencies()}"
}
```

doesn't return empty lists if the subproject defined dependencies for that configuration.

One possible way to do it would be to have a dummy project and use `evaluationDependsOn` in its `build.gradle` file. Is there a less hacky way to do this?

Comment: So are your subproject adding dependencies to your root project?

Comment: @MarkVieira, no. I'd like to add other dependencies to a subproject if a subproject depends on something else. More specifically, I want to exclude the subdependency from the dependency (our build produces `ivy.xml` files that reflect that exclusion so other projects pick it up) then explicitly create a dependency to a specific version.

Comment: You might want to use [`Configuration.getIncoming().beforeResolve()`](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ResolvableDependencies.html#beforeResolve(org.gradle.api.Action)) for that kind of logic.

Comment: @MarkVieira, that's _exactly_ what I want. Convert your comment into an answer and I'll upvote and accept it.

Comment: @MarkVieira, actually, at that point, the configurations can't be modified: `Configuration ':my-project:compile' does not allow modification.`

Comment: Well, perhaps `Configuration.getAllDependencies.all()` might fit the bill. `DependencySet` is a "live" collection so the `all()` method will be called for every dependency added to the collection. You could perhaps put your logic in there. That should happen before Gradle attempts to resolve the configuration.

Comment: Someone pointed me to `gradle.projectsEvaluated` which sounds like the hook I want. The same error still occurs, though, but it looks like, judging from the Gradle code, that error will always happen, so the next question is to figure out how to add programmatically dependencies to a configuration.

Comment: Should be able to do something like `project.configurations.foo.dependencies.add(project.dependencies.create('org.foo:bar:1.0'))`.

Comment: It turns out that `gradle.projectsEvaluated` isn't the right hook since it's called too late. What I really need is something like it that's called for each subproject as evaluation finishes.

Comment: Hmm, `project.afterEvaluate` isn't getting the right thing to happen, either.

Comment: Ah, it was an ordering issue. Once I moved the `project.afterEvaluate` call to before the plugin that generates our `ivy.xml` file, things work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `gradle.projectsEvaluated` and `project.afterEvaluate` can be used for this.